# Does Reinstalling Mac OS from Recovery Clears App data?

Tags: mac, macos, disk-utility, recovery

I need to reinstall Mac OS from recovery since Disk Utility was unable to repair some disk errors.

I have few notes in the notes app and important Bookmarks/opened tabs in both Chrome and Firefox, Which I don't want to lose.

Does this kind of data remain after reinstall? or any other way to repair disk errors without losing on this data?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, reinstalling macOS under these circumstances<sup>1</sup> may erase app data.**

If you don't have a [Time Machine](https://support.apple.com/en-au/ht201250) backup (and you really really should), then the other options you have are:

- export your bookmarks from Firefox as a html file
- export your bookmarks from Chrome as a html file
- ensure your Notes files are synced to iCloud

You would then just copy the HTML files you exported onto an external USB drive for importing back later, and your Notes files will be available to your other Apple devices (or [via the web](https://www.icloud.com/#notes)) assuming you have other Apple devices with iCloud enabled.

Finally, you could also use Chrome's and Firefox's built-in syncing services to save your bookmarks.

**NOTE:** If you don't use iCloud, you could always just copy and paste your Notes into another app from which you can save them onto an external disk (e.g. TextEdit, Pages, MS Word, etc).

**Further reading**

- [Export Firefox bookmarks to an HTML file to back up or transfer bookmarks](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/export-firefox-bookmarks-to-backup-or-transfer)
- [Google Chrome Help: Import or export bookmarks](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816?hl=en)
- [iCloud: Notes overview](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph12081?)
- [Use Time Machine to back up or restore your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-au/ht201250)

<sup>1</sup> It's unclear what you mean by 'disk errors', but if these are such that your startup volume needs reformatting then your data will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy or export everything you want to keep onto another disk before attempting to reinstall macOS. There are two options for reinstalling macOS from recovery; one *may* lose your files and data, the other *will* lose your files and data.

- The option I'd recommend in this situation is to use Disk Utility to erase the volume before reinstalling macOS. Unless there's a hardware problem with the disk, this should fix the disk errors, but it will also result in the loss of anything you don't have backed up to another disk. So back up anything you don't want to lose first.
- The other option is to *not* erase the disk before reinstalling. This will not fix most types of disk/volume errors, and may make the problems much worse. While it won't specifically delete your files, it may damage them accidentally and/or make them even harder to access than they are now. I would not recommend this option, but if you do choose it, my other advice is the same: back up anything you don't want to lose first.